# I accidentally sent a token to a token contract. Can I get it back?

Tags: wallet-transfer

Instead of transferring my ERC20 token to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to the contract itself (the contract, with source code, is [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x672a1ad4f667fb18a333af13667aa0af1f5b5bdd#code)).

Would the contract creator be able to send it back to me?

Comment: use [eth-token-recover](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-token-recover)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you sent a token to a contract address there’s no way to get them back even if the contract’s owner wanted. Unless said contract that received the tokens had implemented a function that allows it to transfer received tokens, they are lost and stuck.

Comment: Another way will be when the contract is killed and then the money is returned. Just saying!

Comment: @Rajat "another way"... Are you sure? I don't really understand how...

Comment: If the contract is killed, all Eths that are in the contract will be transferred, but it's not related to the ERC20 tokens. @11t

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way that you can get your tokens back unless the creator of contract had a function which did that, as far as i can see the contract does not have any such function. Since blockchain`s are immutable and irreversible your transaction cannot be undone .

Answer (score 2):

If you post the contract address will be possible to check if the contract supports transfers. If do, then the contract owner will be able to sent you your tokens. If they do not support transfers and also do not prevent incoming deposits, that is a bad contract design.

Comment: Using the ERC20 standard it is impossible to deny receiving tokens.

Comment: I do not agree, when 'transfer' function is defined, the creator of the contract can impose any requirements (if the destination is the address of the contract: throw) to avoid the situation described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and is exactly the problem and solution described by Dexaran in his ERC223 Token proposal.

https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard