# sending UNI to MataMask Wallet

Tags: metamask, wallets, wallet-transfer, uni

I sent 400 uni from brave wallet to uni metamask wallet, nearly 3 days ago it never showed up.

I'm very new to this and probably should have not done it but in my brave browser wallet i had 400 UNI as well as some smaller cheaper coins. I tried to send my UNI to my Metamask wallet. Not sure if i messed it up somehow here is the details: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x777441d3783417d0429c84522e374398c105bb31b5434383de27b1340bf4c134

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sent your 400 UNI tokens to the UNI contract itself. Unfortunately, this means that you lost them forever. When you are transferring [ERC-20](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/) tokens, the "to" field must be the address of another Ethereum account, **not** the address of the ERC-20 contract itself.

Related post: [I accidentally sent a token to a token contract. Can I get it back?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34559/i-accidentally-sent-a-token-to-a-token-contract-can-i-get-it-back).

Comment: I would have thought there would be some sort of fail-safe on that 
That news is not what i wanted damn, Thanks though 

Comment: Happy to help, @Simon! If my answer is good, would you select it as the accepted one?