# Can i get funds back if I sent weth to a smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment

Copy of chat with dydx chat, they have been helpful so far but they are saying there is no solution, just trying to get a second opinion..
"
Hello thanks for your help, I have a very big problem. Yesterday I made a very serious mistake and sent as WETH in the amount of 0.2400197 (approx. $535) to a smart contract of yours. I sent it from 0x9a941CbE8F6580eBB8eC48DA765B3AD49b1D5671  a 0x8e8bd01b5A9eb272CC3892a2E40E64A716aa2A40
(Transaction ID 0xd53a4a03eaeb4448b3ba31973d2035180a4e9b94a1082dbbfb4085b94eb984fe)
Per, etherscan.io, the address I sent it to belongs to you, I suppose you guys use it as a liquidity address, it says the contract creator es “Hedgies by dYdX”, some sort of deployment address/currency converter you guys use. I really don’t know but you can see for yourself.

Unfortunately, we have no way to retrieve tokens sent to our smart contract. the tokens are stuck there, and we don't have any way to move the tokens or send it back, it is just technically impossible
To explain, this is a smart contract address, we do not have the private key to that address as if it was a normal wallet. The smart contract can only do functions according to its defined ABI interface.
[I accidentally sent a token to a token contract. Can I get it back?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34559/i-accidentally-sent-a-token-to-a-token-contract-can-i-get-it-back)
also https://info.etherscan.com/sent-funds-to-a-contract/
we have discussed this extensively with our engineering team, there is nothing we can do, if there is any way we could help, we would but our conclusion is that we don't see a solution

Comment: Yes, they are right the tokens are stuck in the contract without the possibility of retrieve them.

Comment: thank you, Ismael.